# VS2013 profiler : is it possible to profile a specific method?

Tags: development, visual-studio-2012

I have VS2013 ultimate installed on my SharePoint Dev machine and I have never used VS profile before.

Performance testing shows that performance is degraded compared to the before build and I want to know which method causes the issue and how long it takes.

Performance testing team have identified couple methods and I want to evaluate those methods. How do I use the VS2013 profiler to evaluate the methods and know how long it takes and possible area of improvements?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good beginners guide:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182372.aspx
And here's a good central hub article with links to all the related components of the profiling process. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9z62c29.aspx

Comment: Please avoid just posting a link as an answer. Quote main aspects of the article.

Comment: Ok, you're the second person to make this comment. This question is broad ala I have never done this, how do I do it?  The answer is to follow the very complete guides to which I liked here. Would you have me plagiarize other people's content here rather than link to it?  As a fellow blogger, I know I'd prefer people NOT plagiarize my content.  Look I love Stack Exchange which is my I'm contributing here rather than on TechNet, but as a fellow consumer of this content, I also know that if I click a link and it's no longer there, I simply go on to the next answer and the next link.

Comment: You don't need to plagiarize. You don't even need to copy anything from the blog, just list the main steps that are required to achieve the solution. I am a blogger as well, and I don't mind that people quote a bit and then post a link to the original article. There types of answers do not contribute a lot (not msdn links in this case, but private blogs especially). What if the blog or a link goes down? Please read the help guide on referencing other authors: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/referencing

Comment: OK, I'll endeavour to improve my answers.

Comment: I sometimes copy the exact text (just a small bit), but when I do that, I will ALLWAYS reference where this text comes from. Most of the time I just describe in my own words what and how the author was trying to achieve. Sorry, but this is how this site works.